# Reference the generic type of a generic type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to reference the generic type of a generic type in Typescript ? Basically, for the given types:

```js
class BaseClass<SomeType> {
  // ...
}

class InheritedClass extends BaseClass<string> { }

class Wrapper<AnyBaseClass extends BaseClass<any>> {
  state: AnyBaseClass[<SomeType>]; // What should I put here ?
}

const wrapper = new Wrapper<InheritedClass>();
wrapper.state = "foo"; // Ok
wrapper.state = 4; // Not ok
```

I'd like the type of my property `state` to depend on which inner generic parameter was given to `Wrapper`.

Is there a way to reference this inner generic type? The only solution I've found is to try to find it using `ReturnType<...>` or `AnyBaseClass["anyPropertyOfTypeSomeType"]`, but I would prefer to have a direct way of referencing this type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed like a good case for `infer`, but you can only use that in conditionals... so I ended up with this janky type using a conditional that always evaluates true:

```js
class Wrapper<AnyBaseClass extends BaseClass<any>> {
  state: AnyBaseClass extends BaseClass<infer T> ? T : never;
}
```

There's probably a cleaner way to write this but it will get the correct type for `state`. I also changed your `InheritedClass<any>` to `BaseClass<any>` here, think that was a typo

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, it should have been `BaseClass<any>`.

It's not the cleanest syntax, but it works. Thanks!